# XSLT evaluate attribute value as XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have this `input` line in XSLT:

```
<input type="text" id="CSEMissingInput" class="CSEMissingInput"
       onblur="SetSeriesAnswer(this)" placeholder="[[MManswerInputPlaceholder]]" 
       **maxlength= "SCHEME/FIELD[@id='charactersLimitation']"**>
</input>`
```

When I put a number in the `maxlength` it works just fine, but when try to obtain that number programmatically, it doesn't work.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) answers to your question that have helped you.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [Attribute Value Template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates),

```
maxlength= "{SCHEME/FIELD[@id='charactersLimitation']}"
```

in order for the attribute value string to be interpreted as an XPath.